# Image rounded button JavaFX

Tags: css, image, button, javafx

I´m working with rounded buttons and I want to have an image inside. The problem is that the image is in the center and not on the left even having called

loadButton.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);

What I get is the button above and what I would need is the below button. Do you know any ways of displaying the png under the rounded corner?

[image]

```
   final Label response = new Label();
    final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(
            new Image("recordbutton.png")
    );
    imageView.setFitHeight(40);
    imageView.setFitWidth(40);

    loadButton.setGraphic(imageView);
    loadButton.setStyle("-fx-base: coral;");
    loadButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
    loadButton.setStyle(
             "-fx-background-radius: 100em; " +
                    "-fx-min-width: 60px; " +
                    "-fx-min-height: 60px; " +
                    "-fx-max-width: 130px; " +
                    "-fx-max-height: 60px;"
    );
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

```
loadButton.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.LEFT);
```

use :

```
loadButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
```